# multiply index of one array to a corresponding index of another array. The add all the result together. Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, arrays

I have a form with Qty, Item name, Price, and Total Price. Item Name and Price are information that i will be retrieving from the XML file. Qty field is where user can input whatever quantity they want.

What i need to do is as user input the quantity for a certain item, it would take that quantity and multiply with the price for that specific item, then display it in the Total Price field. Then, that total price field would be added together to give a subtotal. Price is a set numbers retrieve from XML file. Qty is changing depend on the user. They don't have to purchase all the items.

Ex: Qty: 3 for Item 1 : $10 -> $30
   Qty: 2 for Item 2: $5 --> $10
                         Subtotal: $40
All this would happened as user input their quantity. So far, i retrieve the data from XML into one array. And the user qty into another array. but i'm not sure how to make it work. Thank you.

HTML code:

```
    <div id="order"> 
        <table class="bottomBorder" id="torder">
        <tr class="style3"><th align="center">Quantity</th>
            <th width="200px">Item Description</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Total Price</th> 

        <script>
    var xmlDoc = getXML();
    var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("item");

    for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
    {
        var Qty = "Qty" + i;
        var totalprice = "totalprice" + i;

        document.write('<tr><td align="center">');
        document.write('<input type= "text" id="' + Qty +'" name="txtQty" size="2" maxlength="4"/>');
        document.write("</td><td>");
        document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        document.write("</td><td>");
        document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("price")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        document.write("</td><td>");
        document.write('<span id="'+totalprice+'"></span>');
         document.write("</td></tr>");
        }
        </script>                       
        </table>

        <table class="bottomBorder">
          <tr>
            <td width="323" class="style4" align="right" >Subtotal</td>
            <td width="75" align="right" id="subtotal"></td>
          </tr>
           </table>
```

Javascript code:

```
    function QtyValue()
    {   
var Qtys =document.getElementById('torder').getElementsByTagName('input');
var Qty = [];//create array
var error2 = document.getElementById("errorinfo2");

for (var i = 0, l = Qtys.length; i < l; ++i) { //looping through txtqty input 
       if (Qtys[i].value.length) {
        Qty.push(Qtys[i].value); //pushing value into Qty array
        }
}

if(Qty.every(isNumeric) /*&& Qty.length!==0*/) //check to see if info entered in array Qty is a number and is not empty
{
  return Qty;
}else{
     error2.style.display="block";
     error2.innerHTML = "*Please enter a valid number for your quantity";
     return false;
}
    }

    //Getting value for price from productlist.xml into an array
    function Price()
    {
var xmlDoc = getXML();

// Pull out the quote and author elements
var nPrice = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('price');

    // Create our two arrays
var arrPrice=[];

    // Loop through each quote elements yanking out the values and pushing them into the array
    for (i=0; i<nPrice.length; i++)
    {
         arrPrice.push(nPrice[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    }
    return arrPrice;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your two arrays are returned by the `QtyValue` and `Price` functions, you could loop over the two arrays simultaneously to get your sub-total.  (They are guaranteed to be the same length, correct?)

```
var prices = Price();
var quantities = QtyValue();
var subtotal = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < prices.length; i++) {
    var itemTotal = prices[i] * quantities[i];

    // todo: display 'itemTotal' on page

    subtotal += itemTotal;
}

// todo: display 'subtotal' on page
```

Comment: Yes, they are the same length. However, the user get to can enter the quantity on whatever item they choose, so they might skip item 2 and just have item 1 and item 3. I also need to display the price per item (qty*priceperitem) in corresponding to each item before add the subtotal. I can't seem to figure it out. The fact that the data changes confuse me. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: When you gather the quantities in `QtyValue`, instead of skipping the blank fields, assume a default value (probably 0 or 1) and push onto the Qty array. For example, after `if (Qtys[i].value.length) {...}` put `else { Qty.push(0); }`. Does that help at all?  I'll update my answer with a comment showing how you could display a sub-total for each item.

Comment: Humm... that in theory should have work but it seem to substitutes 0 to all my value instead....

Comment: Are you still working on it?  Post your updated code and I'll try to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var total = 0;

if (Qty.length == arrPrice.length) {
    for (var i = 0; i < Qty.length; ++i) {
        total += (Qty[i] * arrPrice[i]);
    }
}

alert(total);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. My problem with using the code is that if user enter the quantity for item 3 first, it would multiply that with the price for item 1 instead of the corresponding price for item 3. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I think then you need to create a 2D array for the quatity. So, in case user enter the quantity for item 3 first, you can store it like Qty[item No][item price] i.e., `Qty[2][0] = 1;`. Hope you got my point.

Comment: Would that work if the user just enter the qty in any random order?